# Incorrect refund import by transactionId in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have an issue with the refunds import through standard Property menu "data import". I use refund import only by ga:transactionId.
As i have read in [help](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6014861?hl=en) in this case there is no need to supply any additional information about transaction (sku, quantity, revenue, etc.).
Whole transaction will be refunded.

In fact i see in report Sales Performance that all refunds are linked with correct transactionId, but have different date, source / medium, etc.
For me it seems to be absolutely random attribution (except date may be, it's date of import)

For example, one transactionId.
Originally it happened at June, 28 in yamarket / cpc. And refund is linked to June, 30 and webvisor.com / referral. Date of refunds common for all transactions and it is date of import (today). Source / medium is absolutely random.

May be i need to wait one day, but i doubt that.

And due to different dates if i choose date range that does not include both dates i will receive only refund or only transaction payment.

Does system work correct?

If system works correct, can i unload all refunds back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All work as it supposed to be. While it is strange logic for my opinion.
Google will change help content to cover this topics.

Refunds are always linked to date of import, not to date of initial transaction.

And, unexpectedly for me, to the last session of buyer on the moment of import. So this session does not necessarily coincide with the purchase session if buyer visited site after transaction.
That's why i get different source/medium for refund and transaction.